# Retrieve database structure in dataset

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net, dataset

Can some one tell me how retrieve database structure in dataset with primary key columns or get the columns that not allow nulls

thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx all some one answer me in another forum

the answer

```
scmd=new SqlCommand("select * from AdminUser",scon);
        scon.Open();

    sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
    sdr.Read();
    dt = sdr.GetSchemaTable();
    scon.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following select in most RDBMS to get columns satisfying some condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'no'
```